# Output of hexadecimal in C++

Tags: c++

This is an example in *"A Complete Guide to Programming in C++" (Ulla Kirch-Prinz & Peter Prinz)*

Example:

```
cout << dec << -1 << " " << hex << -1;
```

This statement causes the following output on a 32-bit system:

```
-1 ffffffff
```

Could anyone please explain why the second output is `ffffffff`?

I have trouble with the explanation in the book that says:

> When octal or hexadecimal numbers are output, the bits of the number
>   to be output are always interpreted as unsigned! In other words, the
>   output shows the bit pattern of a number in octal or hexadecimal
>   format.

Comment: The number -1 as a 32bit number is 0xffffffff, why shouldn’t it output this?

Comment: What output did _you_ expect? The explanation in the book is clear. The bit pattern of -1 is 0xffffffff for a 32 bit value.

Comment: Highly appreciate your quick help. By the way, why isn't 0xffffffff 4294967295 in decimal format?

Comment: @Ng. On a 32 system with 32 bit `unsigned`, `0xffffffff` **is** an `unsigned` type with that decimal value.

Comment: 0xffffffff is unsigned 4294967295 and also signed -1. Notice that 4294967295 and -1 are complementary - if you add 1 to either one, you get 0 (4294967296 doesn't fit in 32 bits, becoming 0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because most modern machines use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed integer representation.

In two's complement, the highest bit is used as a sign bit. If it is set, the number is considered negative, and to get its absolute (positive) value you need to subtract it from 2<sup>N</sup>, i.e. take it's two's complement.

If you had an 8-bit number, 00000001, it's two's complement would be 100000000-00000001 = 11111111 (or 0xFF hex). So -1 is represented as all 1's in binary form.

It's a very convenient system because you can perform arithmetic as if the numbers were unsigned (letting them overflow), then simply interpret the result as signed, and it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

compiler implement negative numbers for signed variables in ths following way, if the highest bit is true, your number implements like  (VALUE_RANGE - variable)

here is an example on 8 bit numbers, i hope you will expand it.

```
char   0 1 2 ... 10 ... 126 127 -128 -127 -126 ... -10 ...  -2   -1

uchar  0 1 2 ... 10 ... 126 127  128  129  130 ... 246 ... 254  255

hex    0 1 2 ... A  ...  7E  7F   80   81   82 ...  F6 ...  FE   FF
```

Answer (score 0):

The text you've highlighted is saying that the output is equivalent to

```
cout << dec << -1 << " " << hex << (unsigned)-1;
```

In a 2's complement system (which any desktop PC is these days), the bit pattern for `-1` has all bits set to 1.

For a 32 bit `int` therefore, the output will be `ffffffff`.

Finally, note that if `int` (and therefore `unsigned`) are 32 bits, the *type* of the literal `0xffffffff` is `unsigned`.

---

References:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement